# How does this break; syntax work in this code of Java

Tags: java, loops, break

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int x = 0;
int y = 30;
for (int outer = 0; outer < 3; outer ++) {
   for (int inner = 4; inner > 1; inner --) {
      x = x + 3;
      y = y - 2;
      if (x == 6) {
         break;
      }
      x = x + 3;
   }
   y = y - 2;
 }
 System.out.println(x + " " + y);
}
```

I was studying with a HeadFirstJava Book (the most recent one published) and I was working on this question. In this code, there is a break statement in the loop. I am not quite sure on which stage that the code will break by itself. Can you show me the process? even if the break statement does not execute, can you tell me why?
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe try to use a debugger to go through the program if you are still confused

Comment: The best way to tell what will happen when you run a Java program is to run the Java program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I am curious about at this point is will the program will start
> the if statement right away as soon as x reaches 6?

-> The program will then run for integer inner value 3 ,
then x becomes 9 and y becomes 26 . x != 6 , if condition wont be executed then x becomes 12

```
inner value 2 :

x = 15, y = 24 , x = 18 

inner value 1 : ( the for loop break ) 
x = 18 and y= 22

outer =1 : 

inner = 4, x = 24, y = 20 , 

inner = 3 , x = 30 , y =18 

inner = 2 , x = 36, y  = 16

inner = 1 ( won't executed ) 

 exits inner for loop 
x = 36, y = 14
outer= 2 ; 

inner = 4 : 
x = 42, y = 12
 
inner = 3 : 
x = 48 , y = 10 ; 

inner  =2 
x = 54, y = 8 
inner =1 : exits inner for loop 
x = 54 and y = 6 

thus the final values are x = 54, and y = 6 only
```

:

Answer (score 0):

The if statement will never be true so we can ignore it, the inner loop runs a total of 9 times where you add 6 each time -> 9*6=54=x
and substract 2 9 times = 18, outer loop runs 3 times total where you also substract 2 = 6. y=30-18-6=6. Not sure where your 42 comes from but for clarification just set some breakpoints and let it play through in the debugger